# Format and display data returned from jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, import.io

I am using import.io to integrate and display a selection of pages that I am scraping. I'm using JS and I think jQuery.

The code is like so: https://import.io/data/integrate/#js

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Import&bull;io Example</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- 1. Include the client library -->
    <script src="https://cdn.import.io/js/2.0.0/importio.js"></script>
    <!-- 2. Configure the library -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        importio.init({
            "auth": {
                "userGuid": "ee034881-d641-48e9-935d-b79819ceb83c",
                "apiKey": "YOUR_API_KEY"
            },
            "host": "import.io"
        });

        // Data and done callbacks
        var dataCallback = function(data) {
            console.log("Data received", data);
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                var d = data[i];        for (var k in d.data) {
                    document.write("<i>" + k + "</i>: " + d.data[k] + "<br />");        }       > document.write("<hr>");     }
                }
                var doneCallback = function(data) {
                    console.log("Done, all data:", data);
                    document.write("<b>Done</b><hr>");
                }

    // 3. Do the query (when the function is called)
    var doQuery = function() {
          // Query for tile ladbrokes promos
          importio.query({
            "connectorGuids": [
            "f6833c85-4a92-47b1-9b96-4c287eac5d24"
            ],
            "input": {
                "webpage/url": "https://www.ladbrokes.com.au/promotions/"
            }
          }, { "data": dataCallback, "done": doneCallback });
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="doQuery()">Query</button>
</body>
</html>
```

However the result of that code is a button which takes me to a new page and gives me a raw dump of the data. How can I parse the data (it looks like JSON?) and format it nicely on the page? For example a table or tiered list?

The returned data follows this format:

```
   {
    "link/_title": "National Olympic Committee of the Azerbaijani Republic",
    "updated/_utc": "Tue Feb 26 13:38:00 GMT 2013",
    "title": [
        "National Olympic Committee of the Azerbaijani Republic",
        "Azerbaijani"
    ],
    "updated/_source": "13:38, 26 February 2013",
    "updated": 1361885880000,
    "link": "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Olympic_Committee_of_the_Azerbaijani_Republic",
    "link/_source": "/wiki/National_Olympic_Committee_of_the_Azerbaijani_Republic",
    "link/_text": "National Olympic Committee of the Azerbaijani Republic"
}
```

I tried searching but I don't think I am using the right jargon and thus can't find the correct results.

Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

You can use **JSON.parse()** on the returned JSON string. You will need jQuery to implement this on your side.

**WORKING DEMO -** http://codepen.io/nitishdhar/pen/jdveD

Looks something like this -

```
var jsonString = '{"link/_title":"National Olympic Committee of the Azerbaijani Republic","updated/_utc":"Tue Feb 26 13:38:00 GMT 2013","title":["National Olympic Committee of the Azerbaijani Republic","Azerbaijani"],"updated/_source":"13:38, 26 February 2013","updated":1361885880000,"link":"http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Olympic_Committee_of_the_Azerbaijani_Republic","link/_source":"/wiki/National_Olympic_Committee_of_the_Azerbaijani_Republic","link/_text":"National Olympic Committee of the Azerbaijani Republic"}';

var jsonObject = JSON.parse(jsonString);
```

Now you can parse this object & access all the values being captured. Something like this -

```
var title = jsonObject['link/_title'];
```

Comment: Thanks i'll try this. Should be able to get it into a table relatively easily I think :)

Comment: Hmm I can't get it to work. Even using your exact working demo, I inject the JS into the header and the HTML is as defined. I've injected jquery etc and the original code snippet I posted still works

Comment: Can you create a Fiddle or something of your code so I can check myself whats the issue

Comment: jsfiddle doesn't allow document.write so I used codepen. The code in the pen actually works on my site (built using square space) but it doesn't work here. No idea why! http://codepen.io/anon/pen/toJhB

Comment: @Max I am totally confused, your codepen code works in your site but not in codepen? Can u be little more clear

Comment: @Max - you need to place script tags in html & only script in script section, i Have created an updated pen which works - http://codepen.io/nitishdhar/pen/bIsen

Comment: You are a Genius.. let me tinker and respond :) edit: On a web page if you inject it into the headers you'd still inject everything except for the <button> right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54685/discussion-between-nitish-dhar-and-max).